# How can I run only 3 packages (there are 10 or above packages and each package has 5-6 java classes) using Selenium +TestNG+Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Suppose I have packages as : com.pkg1, com.pkg2, com.pkg3...etc. and each package contains numbers of java classes. I want to run only 3  packages one by one and I want to store the result status for each packages.

I tried with testng.xml file as below but it only executed 1st package and failed all others

```
<test name="regression1" thread-count="5">
    <packages>
        <package name="com.trest.pkg1" />
                     <package name="com.trest.pkg2" />
        <package name="com.trest.pkg3" />       
    </packages>
</test>
```

Comment: Create one class where you call which class do you want to run and that class only you can call it in XML class.